# How I can execute python virtual environment files with php shell execute?

Tags: php, python, python-3.x, shell, php-7

I have tried to run the Github: https://github.com/atbaker/wikipedia-question-generator

I have created the virtual environment using the following instruction: https://github.com/atbaker/wikipedia-question-generator#installing-with-python-34

```
$ pyvenv venv
$ source venv/bin/activate
$ pip install -r requirements.txt
$ python -m textblob.download_corpora
```

Install the command line tool so you can use the tool easily:

```
$ pip install -e folder_name
```

Now the environment is completed.
My code ran properly on the commandline using the following:

```
wikitrivia 'tony'
```

Now I have tried to use it using php `shell` script as follows:

```
<? php
$out = shell_exec('wikitrivia "tony" ');
echo $out;
?>
```

But there is nothing on the output screen. I tried to run the command `php -v` and have shown the version. But the command `wikitrivia "tony"` is not working. I am using AWS Ubuntu environment.

My `php` version is 7 and the `python` version is 3.5

Hope this helps. Kindly, let me know what I can do?

Answer (score 2):

I did it recently as a cron task.
You need to execute script from working dir with interpreter from venv. 
Somethin like that:

```
<? php
$out = shell_exec('cd FULL_YOUR_PYTON_WORKING_DIR && YOUR_VENV/bin/python FULL_PATH_TO_YOUR_SCRIPT.py "tony"');
echo $out;
?>
```

Comment: it certainly does

Comment: I tried and it does not work. It works for default python system install, but for environments does not.

Comment: But its possible to call first default installed version of python, and than from this python version call any other version of python on the system.

Comment: I suppose you should read more about virtual environments in Python.
You set it up first, and then use, pointing to need an interpreter. It has nothing in common with default python installation.